# How to move models to separate project .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created .NET MVC application and I want to move my models (and then Controllers) to a different project in my solution.

I'm a noob in MVC so I need simple explanation please.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Add a project to your solution called "YourProject.Models".
2. Add references to System.Data, System.Data.Linq, System.Data.DataSetExtensions (if you're  using Linq to Sql)
3. Add a reference from your original MVC project to the new "models"project.
4. Move your model classes from your MVC project to the new project.
5. Compile and run.

Comment: Ok, I managed to do it before seeing your answer, thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project with appropriate name and move the models to a new project. It is as simnple as that.  Then add a reference to the project you are using. Next step is to Create interfaces and implement those interfaces for code separation. Next use IoC (Inversion of control or dependency injection). I suggest asp.net mvc structure map for Ioc. You can use NuGet tool to do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Move your models wherever you want and then update the strongly typed views to match `ViewPage<Namespace.For.Your.ModelClass>` or maybe change the web.config namespace if you do it that way.