# ASP.NET MVC 4 - How to move SQL Server Express DB to new project while deleting old project?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc

I started an ASP.NET MVC 4 app in an old project, then stopped development on it for a while. Now I'm back to working on this project, but (for a number of reasons) I've decided to start fresh from a new project solution. The one thing I'd like to keep from the old project is the DB (SQL Server Express). How can I move/copy the DB into the new solution (keeping in mind that I'll probably delete the old solution entirely after I see everything is working properly in the new solution)? The old project used aspx and the new one uses Razor. Both projects are in C#.

Can I simply copy and paste the APP_DATA folder from the old project into the new one? If so, should I do this from Visual Studio somehow, or can I just go into Windows Explorer directly? If I did this, what settings/configurations/connection strings would I need to modify? Please keep in mind that this is the first time I've done a project linked to a database, so I need lots of details.

Also, I'm figuring I'll use the feature to create the class models based on the DB, once I get the DB in place. Please let me know if this is probably the best route to go, or if you foresee any problems with this approach.

I've checked other questions on SO, but none of the similar questions (including [How to move models to separate project .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585241/how-to-move-models-to-separate-project-net-mvc)) I found really answered my question. I also Googled it and found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx, and it looks like the info is there (maybe), but I don't understand all the terminology well enough to have confidence to start messing with things...I really don't want to lose the previous work because I made poor assumptions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the database, you can do it directly from the folder

Use the same connection string, it could be that you only have to change the path to your DB

Comment: When you say "database" do you mean the entire App_Data folder or just one (or some) of the files in it? There are four files in the App_Data folder: aspnetdb.mdf, projectName.mdf, aspnetdb_log.ldf, and projectName_log.ldf.

Comment: Copy all files that you find in your folder, cause i don't know which files you have in there, but at least the Database file

Comment: One more quicky...the DB files are named with the old project name, which is different from the new name. Can I just do a right-click-rename after the files are copied into the new project folder, or will doing that break something?

Comment: You can call it any name, as long as the name is the same in your connection string,  aspnetdb.mdf, newprojectName.mdf, aspnetdb_log.ldf, and newprojectName_log.ldf

Comment: This worked. I guess this was a REALLY basic question, but in case anyone else needs help, I'll let you know that I ended up leaving the connection string out, and just let Visual Studio recreate it when I had it create my data model classes from the DB. Appears to be functioning properly.