# ASP MVC Can model be separate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Newbie to ASP - MVC.  Using Entity Framework.  If I have a complex database with 100+ tables is it acceptable to have the (M)odel in a separate project?

Comment: Couldn't you have merely _tried_ it before asking?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have the models in a separate class library/project. You will need to set up the references correctly. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6585397/254973 if you need some assitance with the references.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If your domain has that level of complexity, a separate project is a good idea.  That will promote a very natural separation of concerns.